# == for pointer comparison

Tags: c, pointers, comparison, equality

I quote from "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan & Ritchie:

> Any pointer can be meaningfully compared for equality or inequality with zero. But the behavior is undefined for arithmetic or comparisons with pointers that do not point to members of the same array. (There is one exception: the address of the first element past the end of an array can be used in pointer arithmetic.)

Does this mean I cannot rely on `==` for checking equality of different pointers? What are the situations in which this comparison leads to a wrong result?

Comment: If you have different types of pointers and they have the same value, then they point to the same memory address and you might have a bit of a problem. But anyway, it's usually OK to compare pointers if you're absolutely, positively certain that the memory layout is wholly linear. Otherwise, nope. Think of an 8086.

Answer (score 32):

One example that comes to my mind is Harvard architecture with separate address spaces for code and for data. In computers of that architecture the compiler can store *constant* data in the code memory. Since the two address spaces are separate, a pointer to an address in the code memory *could* be numerically equal to a pointer in the data memory, without pointing to the same address.

Comment: This answer could be rephrased as "in C compilers that don't adhere to the ISO C standard."

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to C since object and function pointers are not directly comparable, and since conversion between them is not defined. There's no meaningful way to compare a function pointer to an object pointer without implementation-specific hacks. And as chazomaticus has pointed out, it's impossible for a compiler for a Harvard architecture to store data in the code segment.

Comment: @R.. Back in the early nineties I worked with an [8051](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51) C compiler that would let you place constants into *code* memory. I do not remember if it required a compiler extension or simply declaring a const array would do it, but I remember being able to get a `char*` and `const char*` pointing to *different* kinds of memory. There was also a special kind of pointer that would let you point to one kind of memory or the other at runtime, but it required three bytes instead of the usual two. This was a while ago, the standard was at C89 at best.

Comment: Then that's not a C compiler. C allows `const char *` to point to non-const data (this is normal usage and even has an implicit conversion) and also allows `char *` to point to const data as long as it's not used to modify that data. The type of the pointer is not allowed to alter the location it points to.

Comment: @R.. I wouldn't go as far as calling it "not a C compiler": perhaps its standard compliance was spotty, but it was definitely no Fortran, Cobol, or Pascal :) It wasn't cheap, either (unfortunately, that's the way it has been in the embedded world back in the day).

Comment: That's not "spotty". That's using `const` for a completely different purpose than it's intended and breaking **any** program that uses `const` nontrivially. Even the standard library will not work (`strlen` takes a `const char *` and could not measure the length of a non-`const` string...).

Comment: @R.. Well, that was enough to meet our admittedly low demands: all we wanted was a replacement for the awkward assembly of 8051, and the compiler delivered handsomely. As far as the standard library goes, I do not remember if the compiler offered one or not. I'm sure that we did not link with it, though: the microcontroller did not have a terminal output or a file system (not surprising at all then you have only 256 bytes of RAM); all it offered was a serial port, and a bunch of I/O pins.

Comment: There are lots of languages that use largely C-like syntax and moderately C-like semantics for specialized purposes. There's nothing wrong with that, but I think it's misleading (and harmful, in that it reinforces the misconception that C is an underspecified language whose behavior you cannot rely upon) to call them "C".

Answer (score 8):

The equality operator is defined for all valid pointers, and the only time it can give a "false positive" is when one pointer points to one element past the end of an array, and the other happens to point (or points by virtue of a structure definition) to another object stored just past the array in memory.

I think your mistake is treating K&R as normative. See the C99 standard (nice html version here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html), 6.5.9 on the equality operator. The issue about comparisons being undefined only applies to relational operators (see 6.5.8):

> When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the address space of the objects pointed to. If two pointers to object or incomplete types both point to the same object, or both point one past the last element of the same array object, they compare equal. If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object, pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values. All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. If the expression P points to an element of an array object and the expression Q points to the last element of the same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than P. In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Note that ISO/IEC 9899:1990 does not specify the result when comparing a function pointer with an object pointer.

Comment: -1 You state that *"The equality operator is defined for all valid pointers,"* then quote the section of the standard that says the exact opposite *(note that it says equality evaluates to true if they both point to the same object; it does **not** say the equality is false if they point to different objects)*.

Comment: +1: first answer to reference a spec.  Danny, I think you're confused: the quoted passage is about relational comparison, not equality comparison.  The section on the equality operator says: "Two pointers compare equal if and only if ... both are pointers to the same object ...".  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: The text I cited was about operators other than the equality operator, and I cited it as a possible source of misunderstanding. The equality operator does not admit false positives except for the one case I already covered.

Answer (score 2):

I interpret this as following:

```
short a[9];
int b[12];
short * c = a + 9;
```

Here it is valid to say that

```
c > a
```

because `c` results from `a` via pointer arithmetic,

but not necessarily that

```
b == c
```

or

```
c <= b
```

or something alike, because they result from different arrays, whose order and alignment in memory is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use pointer comparison for comparing pointers that point into different arrays.

So:

`int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

`int * p = &arr[0];`

`int anotherarr[] = {1, 2};`

`int * pf = &anotherarr[0];`

You cannot do `if (p == pf)` since `p` and `pf` do not point into the same array.  This will lead to undefined behaviour.

You can rely on pointer comparison if they point within the same array.

Not sure about the arithmetic case myself.

Answer (score -2):

You can do `==` and `!=` with pointers from different arrays.

<, <=, >, >= is not defined.