# less than comparison for void pointers

Tags: c, pointers, comparison

I want to compare two void pointers like this:

```
void foo(void* p1, void* p2) {

  if (p1 < p2) {
    void *tmp = p1;
    p1 = p2;
    p2 = tmp;
  }

  // do something with p1 and p2.
}
```

Is this correct according to the standard? I mean is the comparison of void pointers a well-defined behaviour?

I'd appreciate if someone can point me to the C standard where this is documented.

Comment: Sure, it's correct. I wonder what purpose it has though (apart from the fact that you misimplemented the swap)

Comment: `C` or `C++`? Of course, they might be the same in this regard, I haven't checked either yet, but they are very much two different languages. My feeling is this is only allowed within a class or an array, and otherwise you must use `!=`, but I will try to confirm that.

Comment: Note that the order is *specified* for only few cases as array.

Comment: Comparison of void pointers is well-defined iff they point into the same array/memory block. (According to C11 6.5.8)

Comment: @BoBTFish, C Standard.

Comment: @BoBTFish, As I recall, they are the same in this regard (except maybe being undefined vs unspecified).

Comment: @DrewMcGowen oopsie. I wonder what could be the rationale behind that one...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Drew McGowen pointed out in a comment, but I'll post the quote here:

> 6.5.8 Relational operators
>
> 5 When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the address space of the
>   objects pointed to. **If two pointers to object types both point to
>   the same object, or both point one past the last element of the same
>   array object, they compare equal**. If the objects pointed to are
>   **members of the same aggregate object, pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members declared
>   earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger
>   subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same
>   array with lower subscript values**. All pointers to **members of the
>   same union object compare equal**. If the expression P points to an
>   element of an array object and the expression Q points to the last
>   element of the same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares
>   greater than P. **In all other cases, the behavior is undefined**.

That's from the `C11` standard. `C99` is the same.

From `C++11`, it's more or less the same. Some tweaks about pointer conversions, I can paste it all if you want. More importantly, the behaviour is Unspecified (as Chris pointed out above).

Note that Undefined Behaviour is lethal. If you compare two unrelated pointers, your machine may catch fire, launch nuclear missiles, make demons fly out of your nose, etc.

Unspecified Behaviour has to do something vaguely reasonable. The compiler doesn't have to document it, or even do the same thing for two different programs, but it can't blow up the world. Your program is still considered valid.

So in your particular case, compiling as `C`, the user could cause Undefined Behaviour depending on what they pass to the function. This seems pretty dangerous.

Also, contrary to my comment on the question, you **cannot** just use `!=` on two arbitrary `void*`s:
`C11`

> 6.5.9 Equality operators
>
> 2 One of the following shall hold:
>
> — both operands have arithmetic type;
>
> — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
>
> — one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a
>   qualified or unqualified version of void; or
>
> — one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

Comment: Err… regarding your last paragraph: Isn't `void` compatible to `void`?

Comment: `void` is not an object type, I think.

Comment: "6.2.5/19 The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed."  Now I'm not sure at all.

Comment: I seem to be thinking of `C++`: "3.9/5 Incompletely-defined object types and the void types are incomplete types (3.9.1)." and "/8 An object type is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is not a function type, not a reference type, and not a void type."

Answer (score 8):

Comparing two pointers is only guaranteed to be sane if they point to parts of the same "object" (struct, union or array) (or one past the end for arrays).

In practice, this is because of the existence of segmented memory model computers, where comparing only the segment offset is much faster than comparing both the segment offset and the segment id.  If said segments overlap, two pointers with identical segment offsets could compare equal even though they point to different areas of memory.

Such systems are less common now than they were 20 years ago.

By @drawmcgowen, this is in C11 6.5.8.

While the results of comparing pointers to unrelated objects (not in the same `struct`, `union` or array) is undefined, I am unaware of a platform where the undefined behavior is more than "does not compare in the order you think it should".

If you really need this, and are willing to restrict which platforms your code is portable to, you can possibly get reasonable guarantees. However be advised that since this is undefined behavior, any future version of your compiler could possibly make this code not function correctly.

What is worse, is that some compilers exploit undefined behavior for optimization opportunities.  For example, suppose you have a buffer, and one pointer at the start of the buffer.

If you compare another pointer to it, either (A) it is inside the buffer, so is `>=` than it, or (B) it isn't inside the buffer, so the result is undefined.

A simple optimization if you can prove a vector is at the front or one-past-the-end of a buffer is to drop the comparison (if `>=` for front, or `<=` for back) and replace it with a constant.

Your compiler could figure this out at any point in the optimization of your code, with any point release.

It could even say "this is a pointer to a heap allocated object", and prove that every pointer is either equal to the pointer, or unrelated -- thus `<` and `>` are *always* undefined behavior, and branches that do this can be completely eliminated from your code.

Relying on undefined behavior means you now have to audit the machine code generated by your code now, and in every compile in the future.

---

Originally this question was tagged with [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).  In C++, `std::less<void*>()( lhs, rhs )` is guaranteed to well order *all* pointers.  (this was added to allow pointers to be sorted in various `std` containers and algorithms)  This may be of use if you are working in a mixed C/C++ system.

## 20.14.6 [comparisons]/2

> For templates less,[...], the specializations for any pointer type yield a strict total order that is consistent among those specializations and is also consistent with the partial order imposed by the built-in operators < [...] For template specializations less [...] if the call operator calls a built-in operator comparing pointers, the call operator yields a strict total order that is consistent among those specializations and is also consistent with the partial order imposed by those built-in operators.

Comment: What does *"does not compare in the order you think it should"* mean?

Comment: @herohuyongtao Pointers to two different objects comparing equal would be the most common and problematic case.  Undefined behavior technically allows the compiler to execute "set computer on fire" instructions: I was just pointing out that in this case, the undefined behavior is mostly "unspecified result".  I would be moderately confident that the order that `<` imposes on pointers would be consistent over time (assuming it is the fault of comparing segment offsets), but I wouldn't bet your life on it.

Comment: @herohuyongtao another example would be from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994202/for-pointer-comparison?rq=1) -- the Harvard model, where data and program pointers are in separate address spaces.  Again, the problem would be that a `void*` to a function pointer and a `void*` to an `int` could compare equal despite being unrelated.

Comment: Some hyper-modern compilers, if they can determine that Undefined Behavior will occur if some condition X is true, will infer that X is false and omit any code which would only be relevant if X were true.  The effects of that can go far beyond "does not compare in the order you think it should".  Unfortunately, such behaviors are will become more, not less, common, unless or until the Standard defines some normative behaviors and means by which code can require them.

Comment: @supercat true.  As a pathological example, imagine you have a struct `foo` containing `int x` that is not standard layout.  The compiler proves that `foo` is never part of another structure containing a double using whole-program optimization (!). You take the address of `foo.x`, cast it to void, and compare it to a void pointer.  This is guaranteed UB, so the compiler can retroactively remove the possibility to going down this execution path.  Any condition that would lead to going down this path can be assumed false as well.  (!)

Comment: @Yakk: If `foo` is statically or automatically allocated, comparison to anything that can't be the same object is Undefined. I'm not quite sure where you're trying to go beyond that, since given `void *region = malloc(bigEnoughNumber); foo *foop = ((foo*)region)+n1; double *doublep = ((*double*)region)+n2;` a comparison between `(void*)foop` and `(void*)doublep` would be well-defined (and compare `n1*sizeof(foo)` and `n2*sizeof(double)`) even though `region` never has a `double` stored in it, and nothing that uses type `foo` knows about type `double` nor vice versa.

Comment: @supercat with whole program optimization, you can prove that no such "compatible" allocation/creation occurs with `foo` in any file, then do the above crazy optimization.  It would be impossible if you admit the possibility of dynamically loading code, admittedly.

Comment: @Yakk: I suppose if the only pointers to `double` that existed anywhere were produced by taking the addresses of variables of static or automatic duration, or likewise for `foo`, either of those would be a legitimate basis for static inference, but I don't see that as being an especially common scenario.  Using data flow to infer that certain malloc statements could generate one pointer, and some other malloc statements could generate the other, but none could generate both would seem more practical; such inference wouldn't depend upon data types.

Comment: @Yakk Great answer. Could you please provide a corroborating link for this assertion: "In C++, std::less<void*>()( lhs, rhs ) is guaranteed to well order all pointers"

Comment: @0xC0DEFACE "20.14.6 [comparisons]/2
For templates less,[...], the specializations for any pointer type yield
a strict total order that is consistent among those specializations and is also consistent with the partial order imposed by the built-in operators
< [...] For template specializations
less<void> [...]
if the call operator calls a built-in operator comparing pointers, the call operator yields a strict total order that is consistent among those specializations and is also consistent with the partial order imposed by those built-in operators."

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @BoBTFish... for Relational Operators (6.5.8 of C11) things are limited further:

> Constraints 2
>
> One of the following shall hold:
>
> — both operands have real type;
>
> or — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible object types.

Which one reads as **excluding** `void*` (`void` is not a type, so `void*` is not a pointer to a type)... so your compiler may well whine at you if you try to `<` etc two `void*` pointers or one "real" pointer and a `void*`.  Casting to (char*) will usually get the job done !  But like any cast, nobody is going to be very sympathetic if it crashes and burns :-)

BTW, the standard is not an easy read, but at $60 it's a useful addition to one's library [http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2FISO%2FIEC+9899-2012](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2FISO%2FIEC%209899-2012)