# Obj-c- if statement being skipped?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a block of code inside of a button that contains various if statements. All work except my last one,

> if (usercurrentPoints < hoursCalculated ) {

This if statement seems to be skipped, and I'm not sure why (I tried to cut this code down as much as possible)? **E.g.** if points is greater than currentuserPoints, an alert should pop up. However it bypasses this, and just saves my data anyway (thus, sending my user into a negative point balance). Any help is appreciated!

```
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender {

        NSInteger hour = [components hour];
        NSInteger minute = [components minute];

        NSString *points;

        if (hour <= 1) {

            points = @"1";


        } else if (hour > 1 && hour < 9) {

            points = @"9";


        } else if (hour <= 9) {

            points = @"9";

        } else if (hour > 9 && hour <= 24) {

            points = @"24";


        } else if (hour > 24 && hour <= 48) {

            points = @"48";

        } else if (hour > 48 && hour <= 72) {

            points = @"72";

        } else if (hour > 72 && hour <= 96) {

            points = @"96";

        } else if (hour > 96) {

            points = @"96";

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uh Oh!"
                                                            message:@"Requests cannot exceed 5 days. Please create separate requests."
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];




           self.sendMessage.enabled = NO;



            return;


        }






        NSDictionary *swapValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:points, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
        NSDictionary *totalPoints = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:swapValues] forKey:@"und"];

        [nodeData setObject:totalPoints forKey:@"field_swapvalue"];



        NSDictionary *enddateValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:formattedendDate, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];

        NSDictionary *finalendDate = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:enddateValues] forKey:@"und"];

      [nodeData setObject:finalendDate forKey:@"field_endswaptime"];


        NSDictionary *swapInitiated = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Requested", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
        NSDictionary *swapRequest = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:swapInitiated] forKey:@"und"];

        [nodeData setObject:swapRequest forKey:@"field_swapaccepted"];


        NSString *hoursCalculated = points;

            NSString *usercurrentPoints = [[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user] objectForKey:@"field_points_balance"][@"und"][0][@"value"];
        NSLog(@"USERS CURRENT BALANCE %@", usercurrentPoints);

[usercurrentPoints intValue];
[hoursCalculated intValue];


     if (usercurrentPoints < hoursCalculated ) {
            NSLog(@"CALCULATED %@", hoursCalculated);


            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uh Oh!"
                                                            message:@"You don't have enough hours to complete this."
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];




        } else  {


            int result = [usercurrentPoints intValue] - [points intValue];


            NSString *resultPoints = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result];


            NSMutableDictionary *userData = [NSMutableDictionary new];


            NSDictionary *targetPoints = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: resultPoints, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
            NSDictionary *finalPoints = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:targetPoints] forKey:@"und"];

            [userData setObject:finalPoints forKey:@"field_points_balance"];
```

Comment: Did you try adding breakpoints and go through the code?

Comment: @Shabirjan Yes, and that if statement is skipped.

Comment: use int instead of NSInteger and see what happens?

Comment: you are trying to compare `NSString*` via `<`?? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to compare the string values?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Ahhhh so I need to make usercurrentPoints an int? How can I convert the string to int? E.g. I tried NSInterger *current = usercurrentPoints and this doesn't do it?

Comment: [usercurrentPoints intValue] i guess

Comment: The most logical path would be to define them as integers in the first place, unless you have some reason for not doing that.  Otherwise, just use intValue as mentioned.

Comment: @Shabirjan Tried adding this, and if statement is still skipped

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Tried using intValue (see edit above), and if statement is still skipped

Comment: Put in a breakpoint at that line.  Are the two values what you expect them to be?

Comment: update the question with what you tried.Show where you changed to IntValue.@Brittany You should do usercurrentPoints.intValue < hoursCalculated.intValue

Comment: Brittany: You didn't change any data types.  All you're doing is sending `intValue` to your NSStrings.  Did you read the docs for that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEM:**

Using < or > with strings does weird stuff.  It certainly won't do what you want consistently.

**MINIMAL CODE CHANGE SOLUTION:**

`[usercurrentPoints intValue]` by itself does nothing meaningful.  Since you only need to fix the comparison, change it to `if ([usercurrentPoints intValue] < [hoursCalculated intValue])`.

**BETTER SOLUTION:**

Use the correct data type for the value. `points` and `hoursCalculated` are only ever used as integers, so there's no reason to define them as strings.  I'm not familiar with DIOSSession, but I don't see why you couldn't assign the `intValue` to an int variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two pointers not the value and the result depends on the relative locations in the address space of the objects pointed to.

[less-than-comparison-for-void-pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807453/less-than-comparison-for-void-pointers) 
might help you for better understanding.